# .NET Core 2.0 MVC - Precompiled Views not deploying properly in VSTS

Tags: continuous-integration, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0, continuous-deployment

I have a .NET Core 2.0 MVC web application that I am trying to get deployed properly through VSTS CI/CD Build and Release definitions. I understand that, by default, .NET Core 2.0 sets Razor View Precompilation to true, in order to precompile all of the Views into a DLL when publishing the application. When I build and publish locally through Visual Studio 2017, everything works fine. When I try to build and release to a web server through VSTS, though, the precompiled DLL for views is not being updated / copied to server.

Is there any solution or fix for this yet? I am seeing a lot of discussion about it online with some workarounds, but many of the posts I am seeing are about a year old or more. So I am wondering if anyone has figured this out yet?

The rest of my MVC deployment seems to be working fine. It is just the precompiled DLL for the Views is not being included in the release and therefore not being copied/overwritten on the server.

Comment: Are you providing the appropriate MSBuild argument to force precompilation? /p:MvcRazorCompileOnPublish=true

Comment: "The ASP.NET Core 2.x project templates implicitly set MvcRazorCompileOnPublish to true by default, which means this node can be safely removed from the .csproj file. If you prefer to be explicit, there's no harm in setting the MvcRazorCompileOnPublish property to true."
See full article here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Do you solve this issue? If not, can you share a simple sample on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Create a new build definition
2. Choose ASP.NET Core build template
3. Modify tasks if needed

Then the necessary files are in the artifact folder (xxx\a).

Comment: We tried all of that already and couldn't get it to work. In VSTS, it is like the DOTNET PUBLISH command is only building (instead of building and publishing). In Visual Studio, the build and publish works fine. At the end of the day, all we need to know is how to get VSTS to build and publish the project, in order to generate the precompiled Views file (.DLL).

Comment: @ChaseHarrison Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share this sample project on the OneDrive. On the other hand, can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: Did you guys ever find a resolution for this?